# VM snapshot taken after backup has different row count

Tags: sql-server

I am verifying a VM backup, which contains a sql server instance. VM restore takes some time, and that means I can have mismatch between database at source VM with DB at destination VM.

To verify if all restore work, I am doing following

1. Create a backup on source location (that I will use in destination VM)
2. Crate a snapshot of db in source location. (idea is that snapshot DB should be exactly equal to destination VM after restore)
3. Take VM restore
4. restore Backup taken at step 1 on destination VM.
5. Stop any job running on destinaion VM, so that I don't corrupt data at destination VM.

As I have taken snapshot at source VM and source VM is production one, I am not changing any job at source.

Also to minimise any time lag, I clubbed Backup and create Snapshot steps i.e. step 1 and step 2, in a single sql server job.

so now when I am comparing destination VM data with source VM snapshot database, I am expecting to get all rows/columns to be same. However, I am seeing mismatch.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you validating a VM snapshot?

Comment: To validate backup and restore. we have a important VM which has DB and other stuff that we backup weekly. Also that DB got backup daily. I have to validate if both backup are working fine.

Comment: any other comments

Comment: You mention source vs destination VM... Is that just in reference to where you're restoring the data or do you have some sort of database mirroring or replication or AG in place?